# Magento Postman Unable to Save Product

Tags: json, magento, postman

I am trying to use Postman to make a POST request to the Magento API and I am getting back an error message that says:

> {"message":"Unable to save product"}.

Here is the code I am running through Postman.

```
{
"product":{"sku": "123456","name": "New Shoe","attribute_set_id": 11,"price": "status": "visibility": "type_id": ""created_at": "2016-12-04 15:03:"updated_at": "2016-12-04 15:03:"}
```

I am running it through a POST request under the `/V1/products/` directory. I am able to Get information from the API with the access key I am using so I do not believe that it is an Authorization issue.

I have tried doing the same request changing some of the information using PUT and I am getting the same result. Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your string is wrong, check the key "created_at"

Answer (score 1):

You can open Magento2 source code, try to find this file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:732

Change last catch to this:

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Unable to save product'), $e);
        }
```

You will see what your problem is. Example: 
[show exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OW6T.png)

Answer (score 0):

**catalogProductRepositoryV1**

```
POST /V1/products
```

**Create product**

> Body > Data

```
{
  "product": {
    "id": 0,
    "sku": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "attributeSetId": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "visibility": 0,
    "typeId": "string",
    "createdAt": "string",
    "updatedAt": "string",
    "weight": 0,
    "extensionAttributes": {
      "downloadableProductLinks": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sortOrder": 0,
          "isShareable": 0,
          "price": 0,
          "numberOfDownloads": 0,
          "linkType": "string",
          "linkFile": "string",
          "linkFileContent": {
            "fileData": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          },
          "linkUrl": "string",
          "sampleType": "string",
          "sampleFile": "string",
          "sampleFileContent": {
            "fileData": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          },
          "sampleUrl": "string",
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "downloadableProductSamples": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "sortOrder": 0,
          "sampleType": "string",
          "sampleFile": "string",
          "sampleFileContent": {
            "fileData": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          },
          "sampleUrl": "string",
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "stockItem": {
        "itemId": 0,
        "productId": 0,
        "stockId": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "isInStock": true,
        "isQtyDecimal": true,
        "showDefaultNotificationMessage": true,
        "useConfigMinQty": true,
        "minQty": 0,
        "useConfigMinSaleQty": 0,
        "minSaleQty": 0,
        "useConfigMaxSaleQty": true,
        "maxSaleQty": 0,
        "useConfigBackorders": true,
        "backorders": 0,
        "useConfigNotifyStockQty": true,
        "notifyStockQty": 0,
        "useConfigQtyIncrements": true,
        "qtyIncrements": 0,
        "useConfigEnableQtyInc": true,
        "enableQtyIncrements": true,
        "useConfigManageStock": true,
        "manageStock": true,
        "lowStockDate": "string",
        "isDecimalDivided": true,
        "stockStatusChangedAuto": 0,
        "extensionAttributes": {}
      },
      "giftcardAmounts": [
        {
          "websiteId": 0,
          "value": 0,
          "websiteValue": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ],
      "configurableProductOptions": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "attributeId": "string",
          "label": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "isUseDefault": true,
          "values": [
            {
              "valueIndex": 0,
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extensionAttributes": {},
          "productId": 0
        }
      ],
      "configurableProductLinks": [
        0
      ],
      "bundleProductOptions": [
        {
          "optionId": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string",
          "position": 0,
          "sku": "string",
          "productLinks": [
            {
              "id": "string",
              "sku": "string",
              "optionId": 0,
              "qty": 0,
              "position": 0,
              "isDefault": true,
              "price": 0,
              "priceType": 0,
              "canChangeQuantity": 0,
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "productLinks": [
      {
        "sku": "string",
        "linkType": "string",
        "linkedProductSku": "string",
        "linkedProductType": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "extensionAttributes": {
          "qty": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "options": [
      {
        "productSku": "string",
        "optionId": 0,
        "title": "string",
        "type": "string",
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "isRequire": true,
        "price": 0,
        "priceType": "string",
        "sku": "string",
        "fileExtension": "string",
        "maxCharacters": 0,
        "imageSizeX": 0,
        "imageSizeY": 0,
        "values": [
          {
            "title": "string",
            "sortOrder": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "priceType": "string",
            "sku": "string",
            "optionTypeId": 0
          }
        ],
        "extensionAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "mediaGalleryEntries": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "mediaType": "string",
        "label": "string",
        "position": 0,
        "disabled": true,
        "types": [
          "string"
        ],
        "file": "string",
        "content": {
          "base64EncodedData": "string",
          "type": "string",
          "name": "string"
        },
        "extensionAttributes": {
          "videoContent": {
            "mediaType": "string",
            "videoProvider": "string",
            "videoUrl": "string",
            "videoTitle": "string",
            "videoDescription": "string",
            "videoMetadata": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "tierPrices": [
      {
        "customerGroupId": 0,
        "qty": 0,
        "value": 0,
        "extensionAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}
```